# jQuery on() delegated events and Leaflet.js

Tags: jquery, events, leaflet

I'm using Leaflet.js for a project and I'd like to bind events on my markers with jQuery on().

I tested something like :

```
$('body').on("hover",".leaflet-marker-icon",function(){console.log("foo")}) //doesn't work
```

but nothing happens.

On the other hand, it works when I bind the events directly :

```
$(".leaflet-marker-icon").hover(function(){console.log("bar")}) //works
```

I tested jQuery.on() on another div of my page :

```
$('body').on("hover",".navbar",function(){console.log("g")}) //no problem
```

This one works fine.

Any clue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

seems that propagation does not happen. You need to provide more code to get more precise answer. For now I suspect that `.stopPropagation()` is called somewhere

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(document).on({
        mouseenter: function(){
           console.log("bar")
        },
        mouseleave: function(){
           console.log("foo")
        }
     }, ".leaflet-marker-icon")
})
```

*Note that as of jQuery 1.8:* The name "hover" used as a shorthand for the string `mouseenter` and  `mouseleave` is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(document).on("hover",".leaflet-marker-icon",function(){console.log("foo")});
```

document instead of body - that is supposed to be the correct way to catch events of dom elements that weren't around on the first body load.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use hover, instead I would use mouseenter. Also make sure that you are using at least jQuery 1.7+ for this event delegation. Additionally, the body tag should be just 1 level up from your leaflet-marker-icon class. That might be the the case for your navbar class, but it might not be the case for your leaflet-marker-icon class. That's maybe why navbar worked. In any case, we need the full code here in order to help.